# Length of a path does not depend of parametrizations

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\phi:[a,b] \to \mathbb{H}$  be a path in $\mathbb{H}$ such that $t \to x(t) + y(t)i$

We define the length of $\phi$ by $lon(\phi) := \int_a^b \frac{1}{y} \sqrt{(x')^2 + (y')^2}dt$.

I want to prove that this longth does not depent of injective parametrizations.

MY IDEA: Let $\epsilon: [a,b] \to \mathbb{H} $ such that $t \to x_{\epsilon}(t) + y_{\epsilon}(t)i$ and

$\rho: [c,d] \to \mathbb{H} $ such that $t \to x_{\rho}(t) + y_{\rho}(t)i$

be parametrizations of $\mathcal{C}$, then I have:

$1)$ $\epsilon([a,b]) = \rho([c,d]) = \mathcal{C}$

$2)$ $x_{\epsilon}(a) = x_{\rho}(c)$, $y_{\epsilon}(a) = y_{\rho}(c)$, $x_{\epsilon}(b) = x_{\rho}(d)$ and $y_{\epsilon}(b) = y_{\rho}(d)$

I tried to calculate $\int_a^b \frac{1}{y_{\epsilon}} \sqrt{(x_{\epsilon}')^2 + (y_{\epsilon}')^2}dt$ and to finish replace by $2)$, however I not obtain a good result

Some Hint Pliss

Comment: Hint: $\rho^{-1}\circ\varepsilon$ is a diffeomorphism between $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$. Try a change of variables in the integral over $[a,b]$.

Comment: What is this $1/y$ in the integral? And why do you restrict to $\mathbb H?$